# What causes grails application to create more threads in some deployments

Tags: java, linux, grails, jvm

Not 100% sure how to ask this.  Skip to last paragraph for the actual question, the rest is background information.

We are running grails 3.3.2 and moving our applications from deploying in tomcat to deploying as standalone jars.  We are deploying to virtual servers that are (in theory) the same across different deployments.  All are deployed on RHEL.

On some of our deployments, the peak/active threads that grails is using are significantly higher than on other deployments, to the point where we are hitting the process soft cap on some servers, but not on others.  Our immediate resolution is to increase this soft cap to account for the number of needed threads, but we're trying to figure out why there are differences.

I understand that since each is running standalone, we have more active threads now as each application has to manage its own container and resources instead of that being handled by tomcat, that's not what I'm trying to figure out.

We have 10+ applications deployed, and the ratios of threads per app seem to be consistent across deployments.  For instance if apps A, B and C have 50, 60 and 100 threads in one deployment, they will be using 100, 120 and 200 (or 75, 90, 150) in another deployment.  The existing data on the servers differ, but the number of threads does not appear to be directly correlated to data size, and since the ratio of data between apps across different deployments differs, I have all but dismissed this possibility.

What I'm really looking for, is if anyone knows what ***could*** be configured differently either on the virtual servers or the physical servers they're hosted on that would cause the applications to spin up with different number of active threads?